# Why transpose in gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent

I've been following Andrew NG's Machine learning course.
According to the gradient descent formula image in the link : 
[(There's no transpose sign)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJbgP.png)

However, in the Implementation, the answer key shows this:

> theta = theta - sum((h - y) .* X)'

why the transpose sign in the answer key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if you call

$$
{\bf x} = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n} ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ {\bf y} = \pmatrix{y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n}
$$

then

$$
{\bf x}^T{\bf y} = \pmatrix{x_1 & x_2 &\cdots & x_n}\pmatrix{y_1 \\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n} = x_1y+1 + x_2y_2 + \cdots + x_n y_n = \sum_{k=1}^nx_k y_k
$$

The difference is then in whether you are using components (rightmost expression) or vectors (leftmost expression), both both are the same

Comment: Agreed but where has the 1/m term gone?

Comment: @Javarome It is a bit difficult to say without full context of the expression, but remember that the learning rate is kind of arbitrary, so the dimension of the problem can be absorbed into it